# Change Field Name Tax To Vat

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PHP paypal Restfull SDK.
When user will redirect to paypal site for payment. as we know display items list & amount information.
but i need to display VAT in replacement of Tax Label.

How can i change label of Tax ?
Please let me know .

Link Of SDK:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Issue :
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/460

Don't know why they are saying not possible.

Here is the proof: 
[image]

Here is the my code .

```
function paypal_payment(){

    if ($config) {
        set_config($config);
    }

    require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    foreach ($pay_data->item_list as $item) {
        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->setName($item['title'])
                ->setDescription($item['description'])
                ->setCurrency($pay_data->currency)
                ->setQuantity($item['quantity'])
                ->setTax($item['tax'])
                ->setPrice($item['price']);
        $all_items[] = $item1;
    }

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems($all_items);

    if (!isset($pay_data->shipping_charg)) {
        $pay_data->shipping_charg = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($pay_data->tax)) {
        $pay_data->tax = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($pay_data->subtotal)) {
        $pay_data->subtotal = 0;
    }

    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping($pay_data->shipping_charg)
            ->setTax($pay_data->tax)
            ->setSubtotal($pay_data->subtotal);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency($pay_data->currency)
            ->setTotal($pay_data->total)
            ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription("Payment description")
            ->setInvoiceNumber($pay_data->invoice_number);

// ### Redirect urls
// Set the urls that the buyer must be redirected to after 
// payment approval/ cancellation.
    $baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    if ($is_for_order === false) {
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(lang_anchor('PaypalTest/payment_done'))
                ->setCancelUrl(lang_anchor('PaypalTest/cancel'));
    } else {
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(lang_anchor('payment/payment_done/true'))
                ->setCancelUrl(lang_anchor('payment/cancel'));
    }

// ### Payment
// A Payment Resource; create one using
// the above types and intent set to 'sale'
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));


// For Sample Purposes Only.
    $request = clone $payment;

// ### Create Payment
// Create a payment by calling the 'create' method
// passing it a valid apiContext.
// (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
// The return object contains the state and the
// url to which the buyer must be redirected to
// for payment approval
    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        $data = ResultPrinter::printError("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", null, $request, $ex);
        return $data;
        exit(1);
    }

// ### Get redirect url
// The API response provides the url that you must redirect
// the buyer to. Retrieve the url from the $payment->getApprovalLink()
// method
    $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

// NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
//    ResultPrinter::printResult("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", "$approvalUrl", $request, $payment);
    redirect($approvalUrl);
    return $approvalUrl;
}
```

Thanks :-)
Ankit Vadariya

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your VAT field with Tax field in your site page where you have redirection process as like that:

**Replace this field:**

```
<input name="VAT_1" value="yourAmount" type="hidden">
```

**With:**

```
<input name="TAX_1" value="yourAmount" type="hidden">
```

Note that: input name may be change but it will contain the `VAT`.

Comment: Thanks devpro !
But i have restfull API. so in my case this will not work.
It will work with simple HTML method.

Comment: yes it will work on simple HTML. did you means u have a direct url for paypal ? @Ankitvadariya

Comment: Yes ! 
SDK will generate URL.
Also i had try to change Tax To Vat in every Word on SDK.

Comment: and your SDK url must have some hidden values ?? @Ankitvadariya

Comment: Nop
We need to create Object For that. 
after that will return url of Paypal. 
but we can't make any change in URL.

Here is the sample URL for staging (Sendbox) environment.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=VK7EUxW6AHHaBQCbWZRFQLTSL7iTzGE-HncnToIwmZtYpOi7AINMZ9EF_Gm&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081984719ecfa9a8ffe80733a1a700ced90ae

Comment: you means as like : $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'] = $this->getTaxAmount(); in your api file. @Ankitvadariya